# Bose-Einstein statistics in de Sitter spacetime

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology, de-sitter-spacetime

The metric in de Sitter spacetime with $(+,-,-,-)$ as metric signature is, in cartesian coordinates:
\begin{equation}
ds^2=dt^2-a^2(t)(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2).
\end{equation}
Where $a(t)=e^{Ht}$. How do I calculate the mean energy in the case of the Bose-Einstein distribution in such space-time? I suspect, for photons, something of the following form:
\begin{equation}
\langle E \rangle_o = 2 V \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{|\vec{k}|}{a(t)} \frac{1}{e^{|\vec{k}|/(a(t)T)}-1},
\end{equation}
where $V$ is the volume defined by the cosmological event horizon for the observer $o$, but I am not sure about my equation.